# RecyclerView creating margins between items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

first of all, sorry if this a stupid question. I'm not being lazy.
So, the problem is, im trying to implement CardView/RecyclerView in an Android app. I made it, but the problem is that the cards are spaced one from another, and i don't know how to fix it. I explored the code but everything seems to be fine.

The code :

RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

CardView item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/cardview.name" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter :

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
    .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
    .DataObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<CardViewItem> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View
        .OnClickListener {
    TextView label;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_name);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<CardViewItem> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.example_card_view, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());;
}

public void addItem(CardViewItem dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
}
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

EDIT: So, i found the answer. The coulprit was the android:layout_height="match_parent"
in my cardview item. I change it for "wrap_content" and fixed the problem. Thanks for the help guys! :)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your current layout and a mockup explaining how you want it to be different.

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried `ItemDecoration` with your RecyclerView ? That's usefull for customize your divider in a RecyclerView

You can look that :
My custom ItemDecoration use `getItemOffsets()` like this :

```
public class MyItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int decorationHeight;
    private Context context;

    public MyItemDecoration(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        decorationHeight = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.decoration_height);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

        if (parent != null && view != null) {

            int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            int totalCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

            if (itemPosition >= 0 && itemPosition < totalCount - 1) {
                outRect.bottom = decorationHeight;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Then you can set your `R.dimen.decoration_height` to the value what you want.

And in my activity, when I instantiate my RecyclerListView I need to do this :

```
myList.addItemDecoration(MyItemDecoration(this))
myList.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
myList.setAdapter(adapter)
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from your CardView item .xml

> android:layout_margin="5dp"

You probably wanted it to be `padding` instead of `margin`

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. Unfortunatly this doesn't fix the problem :/

Answer (score 2):

In order to create spacings in between items, we could use `RecyclerView`'s `ItemDecorator`'s:

```
addItemDecoration(object : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State,
    ) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) > 0) {
            outRect.top = 8.dp // Change this value with anything you want. Remember that you need to convert integers to pixels if you are working with dps :)
        }
    }
})
```

A few things to have in consideration given the code I pasted:

- You don't really need to call `super.getItemOffsets` but I chose to, because I want to extend the behavior defined by the base class. If the library got an update doing more logic behind the scenes, we would miss it.
- As an alternative to adding top spacing to the `Rect`, you could also add bottom spacing, but the logic related to getting the last item of the adapter is more complex, so this might be slightly better.
- I used an extension property to convert a simple integer to dps: `8.dp`. Something like this might work:

```
val Int.dp: Int
    get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density + 0.5f).toInt()

// Extension function works too, but invoking it would become something like 8.dp()
```

Answer (score 1):

CardView by default adds padding. Try using CardView attribute card_view:contentPadding but set the negative values for the attribute like this

card_view:contentPadding="-3"